# How to use specific version Python in Conda environment

Tags: python, environment, conda

I have Anaconda 3 installed and I also created a new environment with Python 2.7.

How can I now use this Python 2.7? Like how can I use it run/write some code in it?

Answer (score 0):

Use python2 in command line when compiling, or add the shebang in your file.

Comment: So when I want to run a python file I have to type "python filename.py"? Is that correct? Even tho I tried it and gave me syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created your new environment with `conda create`, you can switch to it by

unix:

```
source activate py27
```

windows:

```
activate snowflakes
```

For more information please refer to the [documention](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html#change-environments-activate-deactivate).

Comment: He said he already created the environment, so only the second part is needed.